# Tokenize python source code examples (in Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tokenize

Looking to gain understanding in Python's[tokenize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html) module. I am interested in calling the `tokenize.tokenize` method on a given python source file (like the one below) and get its tokenized output with the 5-tuple as mentioned in the docs.

```
# Python source file
import os

class Test():
    """
    This class holds latitude, longitude, depth and magnitude data.
    """

    def __init__(self, latitude, longitude, depth, magnitude):
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.depth = depth
        self.magnitude = magnitude

    def __str__(self):
        # -1 is for detection of missing data
        depth = self.depth
        if depth == -1:
            depth = 'unknown'

        magnitude = self.magnitude
        if magnitude == -1:
            depth = 'unknown'

        return "M{0}, {1} km, lat {2}\N{DEGREE SIGN} lon {3}\N{DEGREE SIGN}".format(magnitude, depth, self.latitude, self.longitude)
```

Unfortunately, the [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html#examples) in the docs is not clear enough given my inexperience in Python to make it work. Also, I could not find any related useful example code online.

Any simple workable code examples will be greatly appreciated.
Also, if you know of useful online material with examples/explanations of the `tokenize` module and its methods that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tokenize.tokenize` is a generator, and it will `yield` multiple 5-tuples corresponding to each token in the source.

```
with open('/path/to/src.py', 'rb') as f:
    for five_tuple in tokenize.tokenize(f.readline):
        print(five_tuple.type)
        print(five_tuple.string)
        print(five_tuple.start)
        print(five_tuple.end)
        print(five_tuple.line)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I am not getting the name of the tokens, e.g. `STRING`, `OP` etc. . Am I missing something?

Comment: They are the first item in the tuple, but they are an int, not a string.  You'll have to compare them to the global statics in the `tokenize` module to `if five_tuple.type == tokenize.OP`

Comment: I see, and how can I compare against more structural tokens (e.g. for an if statement and other keywords)??

Comment: You're going to have to do some work yourself.  Just print out all the token tuples and see what the types are for `if` statements.  The token tuples include the code string *and* the entire line the token appears on.